# Getting below error while executing "pip install -r requirements.txt" command

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I am a beginner and working on a Chatbot project using RASA framework. When I try to install RASA using "pip install rasa" commands or dependencies inside requirement.txt [snap attached] using "pip install -r requirements.txt",I'm getting below error.
In order to resolve the issue I changed concern dependencies version in Requirement.txt but even that couldn't help me out.

For instance in below case, per logs there is requirement of "fbmessenger~=6.0" instead of Version 5.0.0 (existing one).

**ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement fbmessenger~=6.0, but you'll have fbmessenger 5.0.0 which is incompatible**.

If I change the version 5.0 to 6.0 in requirement.txt file and run command then it will again throw error with now requirement of 5.0 version. like

**ERROR: rasa 1.2 has requirement fbmessenger~=5.0, but you'll have fbmessenger 6.0.0 which is incompatible.**

Error Trace :--

```
ERROR: tensorflow 1.14.0 has requirement wrapt>=1.11.1, but you'll have wrapt 1.10.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement fbmessenger~=6.0, but you'll have fbmessenger 5.0.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement matplotlib~=3.0, but you'll have matplotlib 2.0.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement packaging~=19.0, but you'll have packaging 18.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement pika~=1.0.0, but you'll have pika 0.12.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement python-socketio>=4.3.1, but you'll have python-socketio 3.0.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement pytz~=2019.1, but you'll have pytz 2018.9 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa 1.3.9 has requirement redis~=3.3.5, but you'll have redis 2.0.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa-x 0.21.4 has requirement pika~=1.0.0, but you'll have pika 0.12.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa-x 0.21.4 has requirement requests~=2.22, but you'll have requests 2.21.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa-sdk 1.3.3 has requirement ConfigArgParse~=0.14, but you'll have configargparse 0.13.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: rasa-core 0.13.8 has requirement tensorflow~=1.12.0, but you'll have tensorflow 1.14.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: gym 0.15.3 has requirement cloudpickle~=1.2.0, but you'll have cloudpickle 0.6.1 which is incompatible.
```

Requirement.txt Content :-

```
gspread==3.0.0
beautifulsoup4~=4.6.3
requests~=2.21.0
geopy~=1.18.1
pandas~=0.24.1
rasa==1.3.9
future==0.17.1
fakeredis==0.10.1
keras-applications==1.0.6
keras-preprocessing==1.0.5
dill==0.2.9
tensorflow==1.14.0
wrapt==1.10.0
fbmessenger==5.0
matplotlib==2.0
packaging==18.0
pika==0.12.0
pyhton-socketio==3.0
pytz==2018.9
redis==2.0
ConfigArgParse==0.13
cloudpickle==0.6.1
mailchimp3==3.0.2
oauth2client==4.1.2
```

Other Details :--

```
OS-Window 10
Python - 3.6.0
pip -19.3
VS Code - 1.39
```

Comment: Can you build a [mcve], with the *shortest possible* `requirements.txt` that lets someone else produce the same problem included in the question itself? Without that as part of the question, potential answers can't be tested.

Comment: The errors kind of speak for themselves - you have incompatible versions of things installed. Are you installing into an empty virtual environment? If not, I recommend you try that first

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you try to install a older version which is incompatible with new ones. Rather than having all the document i suggest that you can install the latest version of those packages manually.

However most of those packages comes with rasa. You can just install them with:
pip install rasa

If you have some libaries other than those coming with rasa just install them with "pip install (package_name)"

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are trying to install rasa-x in an already existing virtual environment(venv).
Please **create a new venv folder** and then fire the below command and everything will work fine.

```
 pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

Earlier someone must have installed rasa-x. The earlier version had different versions of dependencies and in between rasa-x got upgraded along with its dependency versions. Now when you are trying to reinstall it, you are facing conflicts.

If you have a specific version of rasa-x, say 0.21.4, in your mind then you can install it in a new venv as follows:

```
pip install rasa-x==0.21.4 --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

I have just appended the version number to the package name.